# QML Repeater itemAt not working

Tags: qt, grid, repeater, qml

I have defined a grid like below using *repeater*

```
Grid {
    id: grid
    x: 8;y:8
    clip: true
    smooth: false
    rows: 6; columns: 6; spacing: 3
    Repeater {
        id:table
        model:36
        Cell {     //an item created by me
            clip:true
            color:"blue"
              }
    }
}
```

I want to get position of any **cell** in the *grid*. For that, somewhere in QML file, I wrote
    x:table.itemAt(3).Center

But **itemAt** is not working. In fact, when I am writing
    table.
the QT is not showing **itemAt** in the suggestion tooltip.
What to do?

Comment: It is Qt, not QT which could mean QuickTime and that is definitely not what you want. And accept the answer given if it did solve your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QML Grid Element doesn't provide itemAt method. But, seems, here it is what you are looking for:

```
Item::childAt ( real x, real y )
```

Returns the visible child item at point (x, y), which is in this item's coordinate system, or null if there is no such item. Look [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-item.html)